# Launching selenium from python (subprocess.Popen vs. os.system)

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess

I'm launching the selenium 2 jar file using `subprocess.Popen` in python when I'm bootstrapping my tests.

This works fine with FF but when I try to launch google chrome it fails to load the page (getting a "Aww, snap"-error), it tries to look for it's profile in a weird place: `$SELENIUM_JAR/"/var/folders/Qg/QgltsVp+FL0PDThAc5yUeE+++TM/-Tmp-/customProfileDir2e33faaabf3d4fb18491510228814229"/Default/Bookmarks`

As a test I tried launching selenium manually and that worked fine, next I tried using `os.system` instead and to my surprise that works just fine.

Using `os.system` has many drawbacks though such as not being able to kill selenium and also not capturing the output.

My open command looks like this:

```
self.p = subprocess.Popen(to_execute, env=os.environ, shell=True, cwd=self.path_to_selenium, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Where `to_execute` is `java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js -port 4444`

I can add that I've tried messing with `shell=False`, removing the stdio and also launching via `/bin/bash -c' with no different results

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Your problems sounds pretty weird and unfortunately I cannot help with it. I can, however, recommend you to stop the Selenium server with `shutDownSeleniumServer` method (`shut_down_selenium_server` in the Python API) instead of killing the process. That might even make using `os.system` possible for you.

Comment: Well, I sort of need to capture the output too show errors and to know when It's ok to start the tests.

But thanks, I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: I just realized that I already call shut_down_selenium_server, the problem is capturing output.

Comment: I think something else is wrong our framework and that is not really related to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will simply accept that the problem is not related to python but rather my framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `to_execute` to a list instead of a string, like:

```
to_execute = [
    'java', 
    '-jar', 'selenium-server.jar',
    '-userExtensions', 'user-extensions.js',
    '-port', '4444']
```

Comment: Implied in this answer: use `subprocess.Popen` exclusively.  Use no other.

Comment: You mean using `shell=False`? I've already tried this.

Also, I'm only using `subprocess.Popen`, I just used `os.system` as a test

Comment: @Nicklas A. Your `to_execute` appears to be a string.  This is a list of strings.  Which did you try?

Comment: I've tried both. List + `shell=True` does not work for me, java says I need to supply args

Comment: @Nicklas A. "List + shell=True does not work"?  What about the other 3 combinations?

Comment: `shell=False` + string does not work due to Popen thinking everything is a long command. `shell=False` + list does not work. `shell=True` + string does not work (what I'm currently using).